# How to store PyStan object as a binary?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-data, stan, pystan, probabilistic-programming

I want to store the intermediate files in Probabilistic Programming steps with Stan such as `fit` object, see the SWE below, into a file so I can load it later for later usage. Stan compiles the models in C++ and after each run, I would not want to rerun the models again, I would like to store them to the filesystem for later analysis.

What is the best way store Stan objects with PyStan? In other words, how can I store the stan objects as binary and what is the most feasible way to store the results so no need to run them again later?

**Small working example (source [here](http://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html))**

```
schools_code = """
data {
    int<lower=0> J; // number of schools
    real y[J]; // estimated treatment effects
    real<lower=0> sigma[J]; // s.e. of effect estimates
}
parameters {
    real mu;
    real<lower=0> tau;
    real eta[J];
}
transformed parameters {
    real theta[J];
    for (j in 1:J)
    theta[j] = mu + tau * eta[j];
}
model {
    eta ~ normal(0, 1);
    y ~ normal(theta, sigma);
}
"""

schools_dat = {'J': 8,
               'y': [28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12],
               'sigma': [15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18]}

sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=schools_code)
fit = sm.sampling(data=schools_dat, iter=1000, chains=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options ... best of which is pickle

```
import pickle
with open('fit.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_out:
    pickle.dump(fit, pickle_out)
```

Another option is pandas ... but while this keeps the samples it is no longer a StanFit4Model object.

```
import pandas as pd
fit.to_dataframe().to_csv(‘fit.csv’, encoding='utf-8')
```